# Error while visualizing map from Slam_toolbox on Rviz

Tags: navigation, ros, robotics, slam

**"vertex program:rviz/glsl120/indexed_8bit_image.vert fragment program:rviz/glsl120/indexed_8bit_image.frag glsl link result : active samplers with a different type refer to the same texture image unit"**

Error on rviz when visualizing map from slam_toolbox. Has anyone had this error?

For the first second it displays the map, and it is correct according to the laser scan visualization. But this in rviz terminal the fore mentioned error comes up and the map freezes. The laser scan display works fine even at this point.

Things I have checked:

- the transforms are ok. The odom -> base_link ->laser_frame is up and running.
- the slam_toolbox configurations is good.

I haven't completed the robot yet. Right now I just have a lidar. I just wanted to test the slam_toolbox package and how it would map my room. The odom to base_link transform is being provided form diff_drive_controller of ros2_control package.